# How to send URL to different Browsers when startActivity with ResolveInfo / ComponentName?

Tags: android, android-intent, browser, android-activity, android-package-managers

I'm doing an App that acts like a Browser but I want to allow the user to call his "second" preferred Browser with a button from my Browser.

Because of that, my App is a Browser, I can't call the common ACTION_VIEW Intent, if I did that my own App will appear on the chooser.

So, I made a Preferences Screen that allow you to set your preferred browser. To fill the ListPreference with the available Browsers I use something like that:

```
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://google.com");
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    List<ResolveInfo> allActivities = ctx.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
```

Loop the list and build the preference, I store on SharedPreferences the package name for later use:

```
    ((ActivityInfo) ri.activityInfo).packageName
```

When user tap the "open my preferred browser" button I invoke the Browser Activity like that (I loop again through ResolveInfo because I don't store a complex type like an ActivityInfo:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://google.com");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
List<ResolveInfo> allActivities = mContext.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
ActivityInfo activity = null;
for (ResolveInfo ri : allActivities) {
    String browserAction = ((ActivityInfo) ri.activityInfo).packageName;
    if (sharedPrefs.getString(Constants.KEY_PREFERRED_BROWSER,"").equals(browserAction)) {
        activity = ri.activityInfo;
        break;
    }

    }
    if (activity != null) {
    Log.e(TAG,finalUrl);
    ComponentName name = new ComponentName(activity.applicationInfo.packageName, activity.name);
    Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, Uri.parse(finalUrl)); // TRY 1, set URL on Intent constructor
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,Uri.parse(finalUrl)); // Try 2, put an EXTRA with the URL :P
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
    i.setComponent(name);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(finalUrl)); // Try 3, set URL as Intent Data

    startActivity(i);
}
```

Well... as you can see I tried many things... I'm testing on a Genymotion simulator with Android default browser, Chrome and Firefox, and only Chrome is loading the URL correctly.

Do you know how can I set the URL to the intent correctly for each case? Could I infer how to do it, for example, when user is selecting his preferred Browser in my Preferences Screen? Maybe an easier approach? 0:-)

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(
            "org.mozilla.firefox");
intent.setData(Uri.parse("www.onliner.by"));
startActivity(intent);
```

I checked this with `org.mozilla.firefox` and `com.android.chrome`

**EDIT**
Looks like this is working:

```
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.onliner.by");
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    List<ResolveInfo> allActivities = getPackageManager()
            .queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
    ActivityInfo activity = null;
    for (ResolveInfo ri : allActivities) {
        String browserAction = ((ActivityInfo) ri.activityInfo).packageName;
        if ("com.android.chrome".equals(browserAction)) {
            activity = ri.activityInfo;
            break;
        }

    }
    if (activity != null) {
        ComponentName name = new ComponentName(
                activity.applicationInfo.packageName, activity.name);
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setComponent(name);
        i.setData(uri);

        startActivity(i);
    }
```

But only if I add "http://" before "www.onliner.by".

Comment: It doesn't work always... I notice that URL is loaded if I remove Firefox from Multitask. But if I go back from Firefox to my Browser and tap again the button, URL is not reloaded even if I close the corresponding tab before. Moreover, if I load another URL on my browser and tap the preferred browser button, URL it doesn't load. Trying with Firefox on device this time, any idea? :(

Comment: Looks like the issue is that I'm using launch intent. Os if it is already launched then it doesn't work. I think you may try to use TaskStackBuilder to add browser activity to the current task back stack. I didn't try this and don't know if it is possible.

Comment: @rubdottocom I've updated the answer. Tested on Genymotion emulator with Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: it works fine, I saw that the main problem of my implementation was setting the URL as Data or as an Extra when set it as 2nd param on Intent constructor is enough to make it work. Thank you very much.